# Nginx capture regex from server name

Tags: nginx, regex

```
server {
   listen (my server ip):80;
   server_name  ^(.[^\.]+)(\.)(\d+)\.vm\.example\.net$;

    location / {
        return 200 '$2';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }
}
```

what i am trying to do is capture any of the following domains

example1.1234.vm.example.net
example1.1234.vm.example.net
example2.4321.vm.example.net
example2.4321.vm.example.net

and i want to be able to use the number it got in the return right now its not even matching the server name and showing anything.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `return 200 '$2'` line?

Comment: @mjb2kmn it returns the value of the 2nd capture group (in this case ".") so i changed it to 3 and it gets the 3rd one so it gives me the number

Comment: Also, you should consider using named captures for less trivial configurations, as the numeric captures can go out of scope. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked the validity of the regex yet, but at first glance you're missing the `~` that marks the server_name as a regular expression.

```
server_name  ~^(.[^\.]+)(\.)(\d+)\.vm\.example\.net$;
```

[Documentation here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name)

Comment: Works perfetly i had already read it but i didnt think to check it again